# torch.tensor().squeeze(0) crashing collab session out of ram

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

My google colab keeps crashing without of RAM. I tried to decrease the number of data from 8 columns 73 rows full of sentences to 8 columns 5 rows of the same but it continues to crash. I have tried to change the runtime type as well to see if it helped and it didn't.

I have run this collab with the full dataset and never faced a crash. However when I changed the way I tokenized the data (because it was wrong) it started to crash, so I suspect there's something wrong in there when I try to construct the tensor after doing the encoding.

It crashes on the line

```
input_ids = torch.tensor(profiles_input).squeeze(0)
```

The relevant code ie. the encoding is:

```
model = RobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def encode_df(dataframe):
    dataframe['sentences'] = dataframe['sentences'].apply(lambda row: tokenizer.encode(list(row), axis=1, add_special_tokens=True, padding='max_length',  truncation=True))
    return dataframe

df = pd.read_excel("/content/profile sentences smaller set.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
profiles_encoded = encode_df(df)
profiles_input = profiles_encoded['sentences'].values.tolist()

input_ids = torch.tensor(profiles_input).squeeze(0)
```

Is there something wrong with the encoding part that's causing the crash? Or is it the tensor part?

Is there a way to fix this that is not buy colab pro?

Comment: I don't think `torch.tensor(profiles_input).squeeze(0)` is responsible for the crash unless `profiles_input` is crazy large.

Comment: `tokenizer.encode()` could be an issue though (just a guess) especially since the code specifies `padding='max_length'` so your padding tokens could get pretty nutty.

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan I also suspect it's the tokenizer.encoding. Probably the padding part of it? I get the error "ValueError: expected sequence of length 512 at dim 1 (got 416)" without it or padding to 'longest' and adding padding helped with that.